# IC for Monitoring USB

Tags: usb, usb-device

I was wondering if anyone had ever heard of an IC that monitors USB traffic.  For example, allowing one to man-in-the-middle a USB joystick.

Comment: There are lots of devices that do this (e.g., the Beagle), although I'm not aware of a single IC that would do everything for you. Google "USB Analyzer".

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a tall order.  An IC that would give me pipes for the host and the peripheral would be awesome, but I don't think it's going to be that easy.

Comment: Are you prepared to bit-bang one (or possibly both) of the USB interfaces?

Comment: Electrically it's easy, but the software side is tricky. For something low-bandwidth like a joystick it's more doable, pick some fast-enough hardware (not sure if a BusPirate is up to it?) and roll your own decoder software.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I am prepared, and have a good understanding of the spec.  I was just trying to avoid it.

Comment: For something well defined such as a USB joystick, it might be tempting to use a micro with both USB host and device ports - simply host the peripheral with one, then impersonate it with another.  Or use two micros back-to-back with a serial connection between.  Of course that approach only really covers peripherals where there full set of capabilities is known in advance.

Comment: @Chris Stratton If you know a chip than can do that, and make it an answer, I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would monitor USB traffic, slightly off topic as it is a software only solution rather than a hardware solution:

@m.Alin kindly pointed out that [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) supports USB on Windows too, so basically the answer is: Use Wireshark for snooping USB traffic.

---

My previous answer is still valuable as an alternative:

1. On Linux: just use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), you can snoop USB traffic out of the box;
2. On Windows:

   - Install Linux as host OS on a PC;
   - Install Wireshark, [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and [Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Both Wireshark and Vritualbox are available from standard repositories on all mainstream Linux distributions. The Extention pack is only available from the Oracle website.
   - Install Windows as a guest OS in VirtualBox
   - Configure VirtualBox USB Device filters to feed through the USB device that you want monitored to the Windows guest VM;
   - Use the USB device as intended from the guest OS;
   - Monitor the USB traffic using Wireshark from the Linux host.

Comment: There is also a version of Wireshark for Windows https://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: I was surprised to discover while developing a USB peripheral (which initially worked on Linux but not on Windows due to a mistake I made) that MS offers a fairly usable software USB analyzer for Windows 7 as a free download.

Comment: I wasn't aware there is a [usbpcap](http://desowin.org/usbpcap/) library for Windows. That simplifies things. @m.Alin